# ¿Como puedo dividir elementos de un array para distribuirlo en 4 threads?

Tags: java, hilos

Antes de comentarles lo que tengo hasta ahora desarrollado, les explico lo que intento hacer. Estoy experimentando con hilos y cree un metodo para procesar archivos (en total son 3,000). Con un solo hilo el proceso lo hayo un poco lento... asi que decidi intentar lo siguiente:

Para aumentar la velocidad de procesamiento se me ocurrio distribuir los archivos entre 4 hilos (**SwingWorkers**) para ver que tal va.

Descubri una libreria bastante util para dicho cometido, el cual es [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava):

```
public static void parteUnArray(){
    List<String> numeros = new ArrayList();
    List<List<String>> th = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    int threads = 0;
    numeros.add("Manzana");
    numeros.add("Banana");
    numeros.add("Pera");
    numeros.add("Durazno");
    numeros.add("Mora");
    numeros.add("Canela");
    numeros.add("Tomate");
    numeros.add("Durian");
    numeros.add("Duran");
    numeros.add("Papa");
    numeros.add("cabeza");
    numeros.add("Mango");

    System.out.println("Numeros de elementos: " + numeros.size());

    if(numeros.size() >= 4)
        threads = 4;
    else 
        threads = numeros.size();

    int i = 0;
    for (List<String> partition : Lists.partition(numeros, numeros.size() / threads)) {
        th.add(partition);
    }
    for(List<String> list: th){
        i++;
        for(String value : list){
            System.out.println(i + " " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

Con esta libreria puedo tomar una Lista y dividirla de acuerdo al numero de elementos que yo señale, por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui le señalo dividir un arraylist de 12 elementos en 4 partes, conformado por 3 elementos cada uno. Con esta libreria podria distribuir la cantidad de tareas entre los 4 threads... pero ahora viene mi pregunta:

¿Existira alguna formula o alguna forma de calcular la cantidad de archivos para distribuirlos entre 4 threads?

Como ven, en este codigo que comparti solo dividi la cantidad de elementos entre 4, cosa que funciona bien ya que 12 es divisible entre 4... por ende se van a crear 4 grupos de 3 elementos sin problemas. Pero como es de saberse, no siempre va a funcionar.... por ejemplo, si se le agregara 1 elemento mas, los resultados se me descuadrarian totalmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven, se crea un grupo nuevo... cosa que no es lo que deseo. Solo quiero que los elementos se distribuyan entre 4 grupos.

Comment: ver: [Divide an uneven number between Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688900/divide-an-uneven-number-between-threads)

Comment: Si estás procesando ficheros, quizá el cuello de botella sea la lectura de datos, los discos duros son lo más lento de un PC hoy día